# Android - GoogleMapAPI v2 marker icons out of bounds

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

actually I'm working on an android application using the Google Map APIv2, so far I'm trying to display some markers on a the map, also i want to have all the markers inside my camera view, for this I'm using

```
    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    LatLngBounds bounds;
    int padding = 0;
    //markMap is a hashmap populated with my markers positions.
    HashMap<String, LatLng> markMap = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();


    for (Entry<String, LatLng> entry : markMap.entrySet()) 
            {                                                           
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()));
                builder.include(entry.getValue());                                      
            }

            bounds = builder.build();
            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
            map.animateCamera(update);
```

This works perfectly fine, but there is only one problem with it, and that is : my current camera zoom level only includes the marker points, but the marker icon itself is usually, totally or partially, out of bounds.

## [image: marker icon partially out of the camera view]

Any suggestions on what i should do so i can have a the markers icons included inside my camera view ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just add some padding:

```
CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50);
```

I don't see why CameraUpdate should take into consideration the width of the marker itself. It includes the coordinates not the marker itself.

Comment: i tried this option before and somehow i thought it wouldn't work, now it feels stupid spending few minutes to post this questions when the solution is so easy, +1

Comment: @HossamOukli glad you solved. Select it as a correct answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = 
                new CameraPosition.Builder().target(ll).zoom(16).build();
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

---

You can see more about "Camera Position" [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/CameraPosition.html)